# Нажатие и свайп срабатывают одновременно, как это предотвратить?

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener, gestures

Есть окно со списком. И нужны обработчики нажатия, свайпа(вправо, влево) и длительное нажатие для контекстного меню. Нажатие и контекстное меню работают нормально, но когда я делаю свайп(в границах одного элемента списка) то на это реагирует и обработчик обычного нажатия. Как сделать так чтобы если один обработчик сработал то другие уже не реагировали на это?

Вот код:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] names = {"10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90", "100", "110", "120", "130"};
    GestureDetector gDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureListener());
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        ArrayAdapter<String> aAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, names);
        list.setAdapter(aAdapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d("mytag", "OnItemClickListener");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "OnItemClickListener", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        list.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });

        registerForContextMenu(list);
    }

    public class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            if ((e2.getX() - e1.getX()) > 120 && Math.abs(velocityX) > 200) {
                Log.d("mytag", "SwipeLeft");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SwipeLeft", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            } else if ((e1.getX() - e2.getX()) > 120 && Math.abs(velocityX) > 200) {
                Log.d("mytag", "SwipeRight");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SwipeRight", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
            return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_item_menu, menu);
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="48sp">
</TextView>
```

context_item_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:title="Item1" />
    <item android:title="Item2" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте изменить в `onFling` возвращаемое значение `return false;` на `return true;` в обоих случаях (`SwipeLeft` и `SwipeRight`).

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает, в таком случае вместе со свайпом срабатывает контекстное меню.

Comment: Мил человек, а оно вообще срабатывает? Записи в логах есть?

Comment: Да, срабатывает, и в логах и во всплывающем окошке

Comment: В общем, дабы не повторяться: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833857/how-to-differentiate-between-a-fling-and-a-touch/3834952#3834952

Comment: Увы, я не понимаю как это применить